# Azure DevOps build error running xunit test

Tags: azure-devops, xunit

I am using AzureDevops to build my webapi project. the tests run successfully but it fails due to the following error:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find tests for 
D:\a\1\s\Api\FDA.Operational.Core.Workflow\Workflow.WebAPI.Tests\bin\Release\net
coreapp2.0\xunit.runner.visualstudio.dotnetcore.testadapter.dll. Make sure test 
project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework 
version settings are appropriate. Rerun with /diag option to diagnose further.
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: what are build agents u have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build is trying to find unit tests inside the xUnit test runner assembly. I can tell you: there aren't any.

You should either narrow down the *Test files* setting of your build to not include the test runner, or add a specific *exclusion* by adding an entry with an exclamation point (!) and part of the name of the assembly holding the test adapter. Should look something like the last entry in this screenshot:

[image: Test files]